# What is the difference between com.google.code.javaparser and com.github.javaparser?

Tags: java, parsing, javaparser

When I am working with com.google.code.javaparser , I found that this parser have less documentation and creating new statements with this parser seems difficult. If I am wrong share the coding snippets to create method and VariableDeclarationExpr with this package.

Can anyone compare the difference between com.google.code.javaparser and com.github.javaparser.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.javaparser</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaparser</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaparser-symbol-solver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I found some useful coding examples for com.github.javaparser with their free [ebook](https://leanpub.com/javaparservisited). But I find that there are less articles and documentation that discuss about creating new elements. One of such [article](https://dzone.com/articles/javaparser-java-code-generation) that I found useful with code snippets that can be used to create code ,but this don't provide a sample program.

There are different versions of com.github.javaparser available, version: 3.22.1 . This version supports

`import com.github.javaparser.StaticJavaParser`

but this version is not supporting

```
import com.github.javaparser.ast.stmt.ForeachStmt 
import com.github.javaparser.ast.stmt.SwitchEntryStmt
```

So I changed to Version 3.6.23 where I found

```
import com.github.javaparser.ast.stmt.ForeachStmt 
import com.github.javaparser.ast.stmt.SwitchEntryStmt
```

are supporting but

```
import com.github.javaparser.StaticJavaParser
```

is not supported!

Can anyone share other resources that gives clear picture about creating code using com.github.javaparser with clear example to create method and VariableDeclarationExpr within the class.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it looks to me like a project that migrated from Google Code (the Nth dead Google service) to GitHub, hence the different package names. The [github project repository](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) has links to example projects, in case it helps.